# Is there any another way by which i can store a pdf file from my android phone into a variable and then later print its content?

Tags: java, android

I have tried the above using a library but i am getting many errors:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated /0/document/acc=1;doc=encoded=/V938MsEIOX4CrzaTL3+NmacPQH/8vxm4SrKtNudQ+xYvp9UO6fFD0nNw== (No such file or directory) 
W/System.err: at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
W/System.err: at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165) at
com.example.letstry.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:67) at 
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7590) at
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4416) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4465)
adroid.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) at
 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

The code:

```
String path = data.getData().getPath();  //to get the path of the pdf i want
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + path);
path_disp.setText(path);

PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
PDFParser parser=null;

String parsedText;
try 
{
    parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
    parser.parse();
    cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
    parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
    System.out.println(parsedText);
    path_disp.setText(parsedText);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    try 
    {
        if (cosDoc != null)
            cosDoc.close();
        if (pdDoc != null)
            pdDoc.close();
     } 
     catch (Exception e1) 
     {
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Is there a way by which i can make changes or do i have to use another library .
I have used pdfbox by apache as my additional library.

Comment: it is not clear what you want and what is the problem.

Comment: `.....getPath();  //to get the path of the pdf i want`. No that will never get you a path to a file. Log or Toast its value and you will see that it is no path.

Comment: I asked moderation to remove some comments but they removed many more... anyway, please check whether that path exists. I see a space but maybe that one was added when you created the comment that I copied.

Comment: i tried using log and i got the path  but did not got the file. filenotfound was the error but the string path has a path stored in it which exists in my android phone @TilmanHausherr

Comment: But does this directory contain a file? i.e. a file named "8vxm4SrKtNudQ+xYvp9UO6fFD0nNw==".

Comment: the directory contained a pdf document .@TilmanHausherr

Comment: So the problem at this time is this: Android claims the file doesn't exist. You claim it does exist. It's time for desperate measures, e.g. check yourself that the file exists, and if it doesn't and you still don't believe it, then list all files of this directoriy to see what's really there. Note that upper/lower case may be important.